# Unable to install mongoDB Community Edition on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, mongodb, alibaba-cloud

I have created an instance in Alibaba Cloud Simple Application Server with Ubuntu 14.04 as system Image. I am trying to install MongoDB CE on the server by following the official documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)

I am stuck at the following command

```
echo "deb [ arch=amd64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.6 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.6.list
```

I have even tried the below command

```
echo "deb [ arch=amd64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu "lsb_release -sc"/mongodb-org/3.6 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.6.list
```

nothing works, I get the following message:

```
sudo: unable to resolve host iZrj9gu3lzfytle0g2yhtiZ deb
https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.6 multiverse
```

There are other repositories people used in other references. But I cannot use that. I would like to know why this didn't work even from the official documentation.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What region? From a shell window can you ping mongodb.org? My guess is that your instance is in China and the URL is blocked. Verify that you have actual public Internet access.

Answer (score 1):

two ways to solve it.

1. you still wish to use ECS to build your mongoDB
   check your ECS region, check linux configuration under /etc/hostname.
   you also could download the package on your computer and then upload it
2. you directly use the ApsaraDB for MongoDB service ,it is a better and faster way.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to take a look at your `/etc/hostname` file and that it contains the name of your computer. Just your computer.

I might suggest you this thread, it might be helpful:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/59458/error-message-sudo-unable-to-resolve-host-user/177381